# Iterate through a table to change the children's attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a table for an MVC form that I am creating dynamic list for pushing back to a list of objects.  Using the format for the name: "Object[0].Property".

But I need to make sure that my items are correctly numbered, my idea is to get each row in the table, and then rename the items with the correct number.

```
function reseq() {
        $('.EmpFunctRow').each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this);
            row.children('input').each(function() {
                this.name = "Approvals[" + i + "].appEmpID";
            });
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?  I cant seem to get it right.  I don't necessarily need to iterate through each child, I just need to be able to pick the ones that match.

my first attempt did work, but with multiple items in each row I was not going by row:

```
    var x = $('input[name^="Approvals"');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].name = "Approvals[" + i + "].appEmpID";
    }
```

Is there a way I can combine these two methods, for each row, get the item that matches the name I am looking for and update it?

HTML:

```
<table id="EmpAssignedTable">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Employee</th>
                <th>Route</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Template being Ajaxed into the table:

```
<tr class="EmpFunctRow">
<td>
    <input type="button" value="X" class="btnRemoveRow"/>
</td>
<td>
    <label class="lblEmp">@Model.EmployeeName</label><input type="hidden" name="Approvals[0].appEmpID" value="@Model.EmployeeID"/>
</td>
<td>
    <label class="lblFunct">@Model.FunctDesc</label><input type="hidden" name="Approvals[0].appFunctID" value="@Model.FunctID"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML too?

Comment: @dave I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

1. Loop through all rows
2. Find each hidden input in the rows
3. Get the label that precedes the hidden input and use it's class to build the new name of the input
4. Assign the new name using the index of the row

Here's a running example. If you inspect the results you can see the names that are populated.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".EmpFunctRow").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var labelClass = $this.prev("label").attr("class").replace("lbl", "");
      $this.attr("name", "Approvals[" + index + "].app" + labelClass + "ID"); 
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="EmpFunctRow">
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="X" class="btnRemoveRow"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="lblEmp"></label>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="lblFunct"></label>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr class="EmpFunctRow">
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="X" class="btnRemoveRow"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="lblEmp"></label>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="lblFunct"></label>
      <input type="hidden" />
    </td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```